# Addressing visitor by name after contact form submision

Tags: php, redirect

I have the lines of code below on my "contact page" and I'd like to thank the address the visitor by their name when when they're redirected to "thank you page" But the "thank you"page shows up with just "Thanks for contacting us.

```
<?
   $mailto = 'info@siteripe.com'; // insert the email address you want the form sent to
    $returnpage = 'thanks.php'; // insert the name of the page/location you want the user to be returned to
    $sitename = '[siteripe.com]'; // insert the site name here, it will appear in the subject of your email



$name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
   $subject = $_POST['subject'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];





if (!$name) {
        print("<strong>Error:</strong> Please provide your name.<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;


}
    if (!$email) {
        print("<strong>Error:</strong> Please provide an email address.<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;
    }



if (!$subject) {
        print("<strong>Error:</strong> Please provide a subject.<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;
    }



if (!$phone) {
        print("<strong>Error:</strong> Please provide a Phone number<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;
    }



if (!$message) {
        print("<strong>Error:</strong> Please provide a Message<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;
    }


if (!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([-_\.]?[a-z0-9])+@[a-z0-9]+([-_\.]?[a-z0-9])+\.[a-z]{2,4}", $email)){
    print("<strong>Error:</strong> this email address is not in a valid format.<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;
    }   




$message = "\n$name submitted the following message:\n\n$message\n\nSender's contact details are as follows:\n\nName: $name\nPhone Number: $phone\nEmail Address: $email\n";

  mail($mailto, "$subject", $message, "From: $email");
    header("Location: " . $returnpage);
?>
```

On the Thank you page I have the code below

```
    <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> Thanks for contacting us<br />
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide also the code for the "Thank you" page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the name is not showing up is that you are not passing any data to it. You can update your send php file using the codes below:

```
header('Location:http://www.domain.com/thankyou.php?name='.$name);
```

thankyou.php

```
<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?> Thanks for contacting us
```

Comment: Denil Where exactly do I put em.

Comment: Just replace the header function call you have in your code with the header function call I mentioned above . the 2nd line of code is in your thankyou.php.

Comment: It worked but I killed the re-direct line and placed <h3><?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>,</h3> 
   
   Thanks for contacting us, we'll get back to you as soon aspossible on the about us page

Answer (score 0):

$_POST lives only for the current request, so if you change page the array will be gone.
You could use $_SESSIONS instead to store more persistent datas.
Be careful of having `session_start()` called at the top of your page when using $_SESSIONS.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

On your thankyou page:

```
<?php echo isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '';?> Thanks for contacting us<br />
```

Comment: Don't you think that using Session to solve this problem is like using nuclear bomb on Vatican City? :)

Comment: Uhm, care to explain why would it be so much more dangerous and overkill?

Comment: You misunderstood what I was talking. First of all i was kidding. Besides, i was talking about the fact that maybe this simple problem can be solved with a simple append of the param name to the redirect url.

Comment: Well, the problem is I don't see using sessions more difficult than using GET. And it's not uncommon to use sessions to store temporary flash infos like this.

Comment: I have not say that is more hard. I just say that it's not the case to use session. The session are used to store data in more than a single request-response. Obviously you can use it.

Comment: Where you get the $_POST variable.`$name = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;` Something like this. Be sure to have `session_start()` called at the beginning of every page you use sessions in order for them to work.